# Stop the execution of an Observable chain based on a condition

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In an Angular application, I have this Observable chain in my component :

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-search',
templateUrl: './search.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
```

**search.component.ts**

```
results: any[] = [];
queryField: FormControl = new FormControl();
constructor(private _apiService: ApiService) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.queryField.valueChanges
.debounceTime(200)
.distinctUntilChanged()
.switchMap((query) => this._apiService.search(query)) // was subscribe
.subscribe(result => {  this.results = result.items; console.log(result); });
```

}
}

**seach.ccomponent.html**

```
<input [formControl]='queryField' type="text" id="keyword" autocomplete="off" placeholder="start typing..."/>
```

What I would like to do is to cancel the execution of the rest of the Observables chain and don't go to the switchMap operator (in order to don't execute the request) if the value emitted du the formControl is null.

Answer (score 15):

So if I understand correctly you want to [`.filter()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter) emissions if they are null so your switchMap is not executed:

```
this.queryField.valueChanges
  .filter((q) => q !== null) // only proceed if the value is not null
  .debounceTime(200)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap((query) => this._apiService.search(query)) // was subscribe
  .subscribe(result => {  
    this.results = result.items; 
    console.log(result); 
  });
```

Comment: what if you still want to return a value even null if the filter blocks rest of chain?